# REST API and GET with structured data

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a REST API where given an address, I will return the timezone corresponding to the address. I started along this path,

GET /api/TimeZone?address=

Now this address is a free form address field that I need to parse on the server.

To avoid errors, I'd really like to have the user send in a record like {"city": "", "state": "", "country": "" }

But I can only do this using a POST or a PUT endpoint => which semantically implies that the data is changing on the server but its actually NOT.

What would be a good way to address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple fields in your query:

```
TimeZone?city=London&country=uk
```

Or if you could use hierarchical URLs such as:

```
TimeZone/UK

TimeZone/UK/London
```

I would expect the first of these to supply a bunch of cities, such as those found in most clocks, for UK, London would be the only suggestion as the whole of the UK is "London Time", but for America, there would be many suggestions.